# Error with "null" EditText applying to end of URL in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, url, search, android-edittext

So each time I run the app, type in an ID and hit submit; the end result come outs with null as the ID.

For example: I want to type in 12345 it should go to http://www.hiddenlink.com/12345 but instead it goes to http://www.hiddenlink.com/null

Here's my code:

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity {
Button btnSearchStudent;
String studentID;
private String url = "http://www.hiddenlink.com/" + studentID; // This is test SID just to confirm connection
private static final String TAG_ALLRECORDS = "Objects";
private static final String TAG_ENAME = "emer_name1";
private static final String TAG_EPHONE1 = "emer_Phone1";
private static final String TAG_EPHONE2 = "emer_Phone2";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
    EditText txtStudentID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtStudentID);
    studentID = txtStudentID.getText().toString();
    btnSearchStudent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearchSID);
    btnSearchStudent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, SearchResults.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            new JSONParse().execute();
        }

    });
}

private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SearchActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Connection Test: Logging into Student Database...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    // Login to APIs
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {

        String _username = "hidden";
        String _password = "hidden123";
        String content = MyHttpURLConnection.getData(url, _username, _password);
        try {
// Getting JSON Object from URL Content
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(content);
            JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ALLRECORDS);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
// Storing JSON item in a Variable
                String emer_name1 = c.getString(TAG_ENAME);
                String emer_Phone1 = c.getString(TAG_EPHONE1);
                String emer_Phone2 = c.getString(TAG_EPHONE2);
// Adding value HashMap key => value
                HashMap<String, String> add = new HashMap<String, String>();
                add.put(TAG_EPHONE1, emer_Phone1);
                add.put(TAG_ENAME, emer_name1);
                add.put(TAG_EPHONE2, emer_Phone2);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just change your code with:

```
private String baseUrl = "http://www.hiddenlink.com/";
private String url = "";

btnSearchStudent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        url = baseUrl + txtStudentID.getText().toString();
        new JSONParse().execute();
    }
});
```

I'm missing the sense of reloding the whole Activity

Answer (score 5):

```
String studentID;
private String url = "http://www.hiddenlink.com/" + studentID;
```

`studentID` hasn't been initialized here yet, and so its value is null. Remove the `+ studentID` part and add the `studentID` when you have set it a value.

Answer (score 3):

@Emd4600 is right

You must add the value only after edittext has been initialized and you have some value in it...

To do so do this just define the "url" var, but don't add student id to it:

```
private String url = "http://www.hiddenlink.com/%s";
```

And later when you get edittext do this add the id to url:

```
EditText txtStudentID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtStudentID);

[... more code...]

String realUrl = String.format(url, txtStudentID.getText().toString(););
```

That's about it.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't re-assinging studentID after you click the button, hence it stays null because of its basic initialization:

```
btnSearchStudent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // re-init the student id field
            CharSequence input = txtStudentId.getText();
            if (input  != null) {
                 studentID = input.toString();
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, SearchResults.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            new JSONParse().execute();
        }

    });
```

### Code Standard

You should also label your global variables as `m<Name>` this is standard to signify that the field is a class member variable

### Recommendation

Another way you can do this is to pass in the String into the execute() method of the AsyncTask, that way you can pass in multiple arguments instead of just one, but this will require that you change your AsyncTask to handle multiple queries.

Answer (score 0):

As Emd4600 wrote, your `String studentID` is not initialized at the moment. You probably want to build and run your request when the user hits `btnSearchStudent`. To do so, you'll have to append the content of `txtStudentId` in the onClick listener of your button.

Answer (score 0):

I used what Filnik said and it worked.
Thanks for all the input guys, much appreciated.

Filnik:

```
private String baseUrl = "http://www.hiddenlink.com/";
private String url = "";

 btnSearchStudent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    url = baseUrl + txtStudentID.getText().toString();
    new JSONParse().execute();
}
 });
```